# Why does Greed in FMA (2003) want to know how to bind a soul to an armor?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

Greed mentions in **Episode 33 (Al, Captured)** that he wants to know how to bind a soul to an armor so that he could also be "immortal" like Al. But since Greed is a Homunculus, he doesn't even have a soul, as mentioned by Lust (probably in **Episode 21 - The Red Glow**) as the reason why Homunculi can't perform alchemy.

Can someone explain Greed's intentions?

Comment: Greed is, well, greedy. He wants it **all**. That extends to the knowledge of binding souls to armor. As to him saying that he wants to be immortal, that can be a case of _justifying_ his request to Al, or it could be a case of him (pathologically greedily) wanting a better body (he can presumably change the armor as he sees fit and make improvements, more easy than to his body).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be mentioned in the anime but I am answering based on what I understood.

Ling Yao at the very end of the brotherhood anime mentions to Greed that all he wanted was friends and relationships that supported him.

Greed also had multiple phases when he was reminded of his friends that he had before being killed by the father.

So to answer your question, Greed wanted to bind his friends' soul to an armor and bring them back to life since Human transmutation is not possible.

**TL;DR**
He wanted to revive his friends who satiated his empty feeling in his heart.

Comment: Seems plausible enough.

Answer (score 0):

He might not be speaking literally and is praising Al for being unable to die

Greed has insatiable greed and shows the desire to want something he doesn't even need.